# Is Newton's second law covariant under a change from Cartesian to polar coordinates?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, covariance

I'm aware that Newton's 2nd Law is covariant under a Galilean transformation or under any other linear transformation that's **not** parameterized by relative velocity of frames.

But what about non-linear transformations like change from Cartesian to polar coordinates (strictly speaking not a change in reference frame - just using a different coordinate system)? Does Newton's 2nd Law have the same form even under this transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law is valid in all inertial frames no matter the coordinate system used.  However, using non-Cartesian frames, for example polar coordinates, the unit vectors are not constant in direction, and this must be considered when differentiating position to obtain velocity, then differentiating velocity to obtain acceleration.  See Symon, Mechanics, or a similar physics mechanics textbook for further information.

In non-inertial frames fictitious forces need to be also considered.

Comment: Thanks, does the book that you've referred contain an example of such treatment? i.e. solving a problem in Cartesian and then solving that again in polar coordinates (or any other system with changing unit vectors)?

Comment: Yes, it does. Also, search online for polar/spherical coordinates and non-inertial systems. These MIT videos are especially good: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-003sc-engineering-dynamics-fall-2011/resources/lecture-7-degrees-of-freedom-free-body-diagrams-and-fictitious-forces/ and https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-003sc-engineering-dynamics-fall-2011/resources/definition-of-normal-and-tangential-coordinates/.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider polar coordinates as a way to express the position, velocity and acceleration vectors in another unit vectors (polar base vectors). In that sense, when we apply the newton's second law, first we use a cartesian coordinates as our inertial reference frame, then we express the acceleration and forces in another unit vectors, so the newton's second law in polar coordinates are equivalent to newton's second law in cartesian coordinates. The best way to see this is first express the position vector in terms of the radius(the magnitude of the position vector)and angle between the position vector and the x-coordinate, then differentiate to get the velocity and acceleration vectors in terms of the radius and the angle. So far we only express the acceleration in terms of the radius and the angle, we still in cartesian coordinate system as our inertial reference frame. In order to simplify the expression of the acceleration in terms of the cartesian base vectors, we define/introduce new unit vectors (polar base vectors) to express the acceleration.